# php sqlite3 retieve records from a view

Tags: php, view, sqlite, records

I have two tables, basically;

```
Products               ProductSizePrice
--------               ----------------
ID (PK)                ID (PK)
Name                   ProductID (FK)
                       Size
                       Price
```

Some products will have just one price / size, some will have more than one. To generate a list of products and how many sizes a product has, using PHP (5.4) and SQLite3, is quite easy.

```
$the_sql = "SELECT P.ID, P.Name, COUNT(1) AS Sizes
            FROM Product AS P INNER JOIN ProductSizePrice AS PC 
                   ON (P.ID = PC.ProductID)
            GROUP BY P.ID, P.Name"
$db = new SQLite3('DatabasePathName');
$rec = $db->query($the_sql);

while ($row = $rec->fetchArray()) {
    ...
}
```

This works well (sorry for being obvious).

Creating a View within this SQLite3 DB;

```
CREATE VIEW [ProductSizeCount] AS
       SELECT [P].[ID], [P].[Name], COUNT([PC].[ID]) AS [Sizes]
         FROM [Product] AS [P] INNER JOIN [ProductSizePrice] AS [PC]
                      ON ([P].[ID] = [PC].[ProductID]) 
         GROUP BY [P].[ID], [P].[Name];
```

Such that, I now have a View describing the sql statement above, I then change the sql to;

```
$this_sql = "SELECT P.ID, P.Name, P.Sizes FROM ProductSizeCount AS P";
```

When the command is executed it yields exceptions,

**Warning:** SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, no such table: ProductSizeCount in **..\index.php on line ...**

**Fatal error:** Call to a member function fetchArray() on a non-object in **..\index.php on line ...**

My question being, a part from what am I doing wrong is, this cannot be done with SQLite3 Views?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: According to the error message, the `ProductSizeCount` view does not exist in that database.

Comment: @CL, you're correct $this_sql = "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type IN ('table', 'view');", will list all tables, but none of the views. Despite the view showing up in the SQLiteStudio v2.1.5 IDE. I'm not at a complete loss. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Created the views using SQLiteman v1.2.2 instead of SQLiteStudio v2.1.5. The view does indeed exist now, and the above works. Once again thanks CL, your response has eventually lead me to a working solution.